# increase max_connections in mysql on ubuntu wily

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ulimit, sysctl

I have ubuntu wily installed on my server. 
I'm trying to increase max_connections of mysql server to 1237
but when running mysql client and executing `show variables like 'max_connections';` i get 214.

i did the following:

i edit /etc/sysctl.conf and added `fs.file-max = 2459688` then executed `sysctl -p`.

I edited /etc/security/limit.conf and added the following lines:

```
*           soft    nofile         4096
*           hard    nofile         4096
```

then rebooted. ulimit -a shows 4096, but mysql proc still shows soft 1024 connections.

which means.. I do the following commands:

```
# cat /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
1099
# cat /proc/1099/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             62891                62891                processes
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       62891                62891                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12061/mysql-auto-adjusting-max-connections-values

in the question i posted above, someone tried to increase the max opened files for mysql. when I did what he did,  i could increase the max_connections to whatever i want.